# How to upload file with form-post using c++ Qt-WebKit?

Tags: qt, webkit

So, when i was dealing with forms before what i would do is find web element that is part of the form input, set value of that form input by element.setattribute("value", "infoi want to add")

then simply when i set value of form elements i click submit button of form.

Is this possible to do with web-form input type="file" and how can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and the most straightforward way to do exactly what you've described is to get form's target address with [QWebFrame::hitTestContent](http://doc.troll.no/4.7/qwebframe.html#hitTestContent) and then to post a file with [QNetworkAccessManager::post](http://doc.troll.no/4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#post).  You also could inject some javascript code into a loaded page (see [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit-bridge.html) for more details), but that would be an overkill for such a simple taks.  And besides in the latter case all your injected javascript will be gone after submitting the form (i.e. after the page is reloaded).